# Ionic custom pagination like inshorts app phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, ionic-framework, pagination

I am making an hybrid news app similar to InShorts in ionic framework using phonegap, I need to implement custom pagination like that of InShorts app (full page moving to top on swipe event), I am newbie to ionic please help me how to achieve that.

I have got this - [Swipe effect like inshorts news app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065003/swipe-effect-like-inshorts-news-app) but it is Android native code and i need to implement it in Phonegap using ionic framework

Thanks.
Krunal

Answer (score 0):

Slides make it easy to create galleries, tutorials, and page-based layouts.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#slides